# How do I interpret this application of the safe bool idiom?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding some code that I believe is an application of the [Safe Bool Idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool). This is framework code I don't have the opportunity to change, and understand the modern way of achieving this is just using `explicit operator bool()`.

I've read the question marked as duplicate, but I think this situation is different. In fact, the answer to that question is pointing out there is a difference between `void (ClassType::*func_pointer_name)` and `void Classtype::*`. My question asks what the latter means and why it works in this case.

The class in question is a wrapper around a `boost::shared_ptr` to an implementation type, or `internal` in the minimal (I think) example I've tested:

```
class TestWrapper {
public:
    explicit TestWrapper(int* ptr) : internal(ptr) {}


    typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::* safe_bool;

    boost::shared_ptr<int> internal;

    bool operator!() { return !internal; }
    operator safe_bool() const { return internal ? &TestWrapper::internal : 0; }
};
```

The output of my test program is what I'd expect for various tests on a `boost::shared_ptr` Each line is an expression that tested as `true`. `null` is `TestWrapper null(nullptr)` and `nonnull` is `TestWrapper nonnull(new int(10))`:

```
$ g++ nullptr.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out
!null
null == nullptr
null == 0
nonnull
nonnull != nullptr
nonnull != 0
```

I'm confused by the typedef:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::* safe_bool;
```

I understand here I'm creating a type `safe_bool`, but what does `boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::*` mean?

I'm also confused by the conversion operator:

```
operator safe_bool() const { return internal ? &TestWrapper::internal : 0; }
```

I understand I'm converting to the `safe_bool` type created above, and that if `internal` is valid, it returns that or 0. What does `&TestWrapper::internal` mean? Why can `0` be used as a substitute?

The full test program is here:

```cpp
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class TestWrapper {
public:
    explicit TestWrapper(int* ptr) : internal(ptr) {}


    typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::* safe_bool;

    boost::shared_ptr<int> internal;

    bool operator!() { return !internal; }
    operator safe_bool() const { return internal ? &TestWrapper::internal : 0; }
};

int main() {
    TestWrapper null(nullptr);
    TestWrapper nonnull(new int(10));

    if(!null) {
        std::cout << "!null" << std::endl;
    }

    if(null) {
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
    }

    if(null == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "null == nullptr" << std::endl;
    }

    if(null != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "null != nullptr" << std::endl;
    }

    if(null == 0) {
        std::cout << "null == 0" << std::endl;
    }

    if(null != 0) {
        std::cout << "null != 0" << std::endl;
    }

    if(!nonnull) {
        std::cout << "!nonnull" << std::endl;
    }

    if(nonnull) {
        std::cout << "nonnull" << std::endl;
    }

    if(nonnull == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "nonnull == nullptr" << std::endl;
    }

    if(nonnull != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "nonnull != nullptr" << std::endl;
    }

    if(nonnull == 0) {
        std::cout << "nonnull == 0" << std::endl;
    }

    if(nonnull != 0) {
        std::cout << "nonnull != 0" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I've read the duplicate as well, but I think this situation is different. In fact, the answer to that question is pointing out there is a difference between `void (ClassType::*func_pointer)` and `void Classtype::*`. My quesion asks what the latter means.